# Write windows mini dumps with Python

Tags: python, windows, winapi, minidump

I've been trying to create a function that will write a minidump file for a given process ID. So far I have this:

```
import win32con, win32api, win32file, ctypes
dbghelp = ctypes.windll.dbghelp 

def createMiniDump(pid, file_name):
    # Adjust privileges.
    adjustPrivilege(win32security.SE_DEBUG_NAME)
    pHandle = win32api.OpenProcess(
                win32con.PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION | win32con.PROCESS_VM_READ ,
                0, pid)
    print 'pHandle Status: ', win32api.FormatMessage(win32api.GetLastError())
    fHandle = win32file.CreateFile(file_name,
                               win32file.GENERIC_READ | win32file.GENERIC_WRITE,
                               win32file.FILE_SHARE_READ | win32file.FILE_SHARE_WRITE,
                               None,
                               win32file.CREATE_ALWAYS,
                               win32file.FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,
                               None)

    print 'fHandle Status: ', win32api.FormatMessage(win32api.GetLastError())
    success = dbghelp.MiniDumpWriteDump(pHandle.handle,   # Process handle
                                     pid,                 # Process ID
                                     fHandle.handle,      # File handle
                                     0,         # Dump type - MiniDumpNormal
                                     None,      # Exception parameter
                                     None,      # User stream parameter
                                     None,      # Callback parameter
                                     )
    print 'MiniDump Status: ', win32api.FormatMessage(win32api.GetLastError())
    return success
```

The process and file handles are created successfully. However, the call to MiniDumpWriteDump sets the following error: 
    `Only part of a ReadProcessMemory or WriteProcessMemory request was completed.`

Does anyone have any ideas of why this is happening?

Comment: What is the value of `dump_type`? I assume this is set externally to the function?

Comment: The value of dump_type is 0 (MiniDumpNormal). Sorry, bad copy and paste on my part. Fixed this in the question.

Comment: I have in the past successfully created a dump file from processes that have not raised an exception by using different tools.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only issues I've ever encountered would be is cross architecture dumps ie dumping a 32 bit processes when your local process is a 64 bit process or vice versa.  If you look around the net you can find plenty of references to the standard recomendation is to take a 32 bit dump from a 32 bit process and a 64 from a 64.  see [Do not collect 32bit process' dumps with 64 bit task manager](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/amb/archive/2011/05/12/do-not-collect-32bit-process-dumps-with-64bit-task-manager.aspx)  and [Capturing memory dumps for 32-bit processes on an x64 machine](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tess/archive/2010/09/29/capturing-memory-dumps-for-32-bit-processes-on-an-x64-machine.aspx)
 I don't know why, but I'd like to. (even though technically on x64 windows they all *are* 64 bit processes, the 32 bit ones are just lying to themselves.. with an extra thread stack and TEB and PEB.

The exception pointers and current Thread id are only relevant when you are dumping from within the process.
  If you read the MSDN entry completely it suggests creating a helper thread and excluding it from the dump to get the current thread stack meaningfully which obviously only has meaning if you are dumping the current process.
  Also dumping an external process which is very helpful sometimes in diagnosing hanging processes wouldn't have PEXCEPTION_POINTER information. Also I have done *plenty* of minidumps of external processes without PEXCEPTION_POINTER  being set, or callback, but callback is very useful.

Comment: The code worked all along! As soon as the architecture of the calling process matched the target process, it started working. Thanks for answer!

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a prepared `MINIDUMP_EXCEPTION_INFORMATION` structure as the 5th parameter to `MiniDumpWriteDump()`.  It's necessary for a successful dump.

Set its `ThreadId` field to `GetCurrentThreadId()`.  Set its `ClientPointers` field to FALSE.  The real trick here is the `ExceptionPointers` field.  The only way I know of getting a `PEXCEPTION_POINTERS` is via a callback assigned through `AddVectoredExceptionHandler()`.  The callback gets passed a single `PEXCEPTION_POINTERS` parameter.  So, you'll need to move all your dump code into that callback to have access to a `PEXCEPTION_POINTERS` at the time of the dump.  Unfortunately, this also means that you're at the mercy of an unhandled exception triggering the dump (unless you can find another way to get a `PEXCEPTION_POINTERS`).

Comment: This makes sense. However, shouldn't ClientPointers be set to True since the dump being collected is in a different process space than the calling process? Also, I don't really care about creating a dump when an exception happens. My idea was to create the dump file on demand, even if there are no exceptions on the target process.

Comment: Sorry, I don't think it's possible to generate a complete minidump without triggering an exception.  See 3rd paragraph of remarks about [MiniDumpWriteDump](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680360(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: I have in the past successfully created a dump file from processes that have not raised an exception by using different tools.

Comment: So? The original question is why does `MiniDumpWriteDump()` give a partial dump error. It's because `MINIDUMP_EXCEPTION_INFORMATION` is missing.  Maybe the intended question was "How can a complete minidump be created from python?" but that's not what was asked.

Comment: The error is that a partial dump was created. However the file is empty.